# What additional aircraft equipment is required to fly a US registered airplane in Europe?

Tags: faa-regulations, easa-regulations

If I want to take an airplane to Europe, what additional aircraft equipment is required beyond the US requirements?

For instance, I know that we need 8.33Khz spacing radios, what else is there?

Also, I heard that it will be changing in 2015 to have additional requirements.  What will those be, and will there be any exceptions (ie, can we obtain a waiver)?

Comment: You only need 8.33kHz spacing above FL195 in Europe

Comment: @PhilippeLeybaert Good to know, but that applies to me!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An overview of ATC related avionics can be found on the [Eurocontrol website](http://www.eurocontrol.int/articles/requirements-civil-aircraft). There are a couple of things changing in 2015.

The list below includes change to ATC related avionics requirements in 2015.

In addition other avionic requirements not related to ATC are imposed, but that is outside my field of expertise.

---

### **Surveillance**

[Commission Implementing Rule (IR) (EU) No 1207/2011](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2011:305:0035:0052:EN:PDF)

[Commission Implementing Rule (IR) (EU) No 1028/2014 (Amendment of 1207/2011)](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32014R1028&from=EN)

**ADS-B**

ADS-B (1090ES) will be mandated  from 7 January 2017 for aircraft with MTOM > 5700 kg and Max cruise TAS > 250 Kts with an individual  certificate  of  airworthiness  first  issued on or after 8 June 2016. For aircraft certified before 8 June 2016 with the same MTOM and max cruise speed class ADS-B will be mandated after 7 June 2020 .

Applies to all IFR flights in the European Civil Aviation Conference (ECAC) airspace, excluding oversea territories.

**Mode-S Elementary Surveillance (ELS)**

Mode S ELS will be mandated for all aircraft operating according to Instrument Flight Rules from 8 January 2015

Applies to all IFR flights in the ECAC airspace, excluding oversea territories.

**Mode-S Enhanced Surveillance (EHS)**

Mode S EHS will be mandated for **new** aircraft with MTOM > 5700 kg and Max cruise TAS > 250 Kts from 8 January 2015. For existing aircraft in the same MTOM and max cruise speed class Mode S EHS will be mandated after 7 December 2017.

Applies to all IFR flights in the ECAC airspace, excluding oversea territories.

---

### Communication

[Commission Implementing Rule (IR)(EU) No 29/2009](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2009:013:0003:0019:EN:PDF)

**Controller-Pilot Data Link Communications (CPDLC)**

CPDLC (VDL Mode 2) is mandated above FL285 from 5 February 2015

Applies to all IFR flights in the ECAC airspace, excluding oversea territories.

---

### Safety Enhancements

[Commission Implementing Rule (IR) (EU) No 1332/2011](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2011:336:0020:0022:EN:PDF)

**TCAS**

From 1 December 2015 TCAS II version 7.1  will be mandated for all aircraft build before March 2012 with MTOM > 5700 kg and Max cruise TAS > 250 Kts operating in EU airspace. Aircraft first certified after 1 March 2012 already need to operate with TCAS II version 7.1.

Outside EU airspace, but within ECAC airspace, TCAS version 7.0 is still allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I really depends on what kind of aircraft we are talking abut. All the additional avionics @DeltaLima already has mentioned correctly effect aircraft with a MTOM of 5700kg or greater. If you think about some smaller G/A planes like a Cherokee or Skyhawk you should consider additional noise abatement. If you don't fulfill some requirements regarding noise abatement you will most probably spend a lot more money on landing fees or even meight be not allowed to land at some airports. I honestly don't know about noise regulations for bigger aircraft, but I guess that the differences between the US and Europe at this point are most significant at light types.

Comment: Can you expand a little on the European noise abatement rules/requirements (perhaps with some examples)? Are the additional requirements procedural, or is there equipment that needs to be added/removed/modified to comply?

Comment: I will ad least try to, but I only know about the german rules in detail. I would like to provide you with my reference, but unfortunately it's from a German law book - how about your german?? ;) I'll add some of it to myanswer shortly.

Comment: I can generally manage to order food and drinks in German without getting myself poisoned - for everything else there's Google Translate :-) I'm mainly interested in the idea of noise abatement equipment as a regulatory construct (in the US most of it is "noise abatement *procedures*" - I've heard tell that other countries actually require specific equipment/modifications to the aircraft but it's quite literally a *foreign* concept to me :)

Comment: To give you a basic idea: In Germany laws exist that state, that aircraft are either not allowed to create more than a specified ammount of noise dependent on their age, their mass and the way they are driven, ore can only be operated with many restrictions. These restrictions may be different from airpirt to airport and meight even prohibit the operation of the effected aircraf on the field regardless of the day or time (most restrictions are time restrictions or prohibit some kind of operation on specific days of the week) Also airports use the mising certificates to raise the lsnding fees.