# Is implementation of CPDLC mandated by EASA?

Tags: icao, easa, cpdlc, acars

Is CPDLC (Controller–pilot data link communications) mandatory by EASA? I have not heard any update that Airlines are using CPDLC. While talking to some of the pilots I heard that they have been instructed to switch the System due to satellite cost. What is the real scenario?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Which airplanes are exempt from Europe's 2015 CPDLC (Link 2000+) requirement?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1787/69).  While the subject doesn't look like an **exact** duplicate, it does address this question as well.

Comment: A better duplicate: [What additional aircraft equipment is required to fly a US registered airplane in Europe?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/766/69)

Answer (score 1):

according to eurocontrol, http://www.eurocontrol.int/services/link-2000-programme:

> The LINK 2000+ Programme started in 2001 and is now in the full scale
>   implementation phase governed by the DLS IR which requires:
>
> • All newly delivered aircraft operating above FL285 to be equipped as
>   of 2011,
>
> • Core European ANSPs to be operational by 7 February  2013,
>
> • The rest of European ANSPs to be operational by 5 February 2015,
>
> • All existing aircraft operating above FL295 to be retroffited by 5
>   Feb 2015 (unless exempt).

What aircraft are exempt? See page 4 of this pdf: http://ec.europa.eu/transport/modes/air/single_european_sky/doc/implementing_rules/2014_01_22_2nd_exemption_under_29_2009.pdf